# Are there any automatic time trackers for KDE desktop activities?

Tags: software-recommendation, kde

I'm using KDE activities for my few tasks. And I have to track time for each of them. Is there any time tracker software for KDE which can automatically track time for different activities while I'm switching between them?

At the moment, I'm using KTimeTracker, but it seems to not be updated and has some bugs with the history exporting. It can automatically track only different desktops, not activities.

Comment: As in tracks what application you're using when?